# Addition and multiplication in a Galois Field

Tags: math, qr-code, reed-solomon, galois-field

I am attempting to generate QR codes on an extremely limited embedded platform. Everything in [the specification](http://raidenii.net/files/datasheets/misc/qr_code.pdf) seems fairly straightforward except for generating the error correction codewords. I have looked at a bunch of existing implementations, and they all try to implement  a bunch of polynomial math that goes straight over my head, particularly with regards to the Galois fields. The most straightforward way I can see, both in mathematical complexity and in memory requirements is a circuit concept that is laid out in the spec itself:

[image: circuit diagram]

With their description, I am fairly confident I could implement this with the exception of the parts labeled GF(256) addition and GF(256) Multiplication.

They offer this help:

> The polynomial arithmetic for QR Code shall be calculated using bit-wise modulo 2 arithmetic and byte-wise
>   modulo 100011101 arithmetic. This is a Galois field of 2^8
>   with 100011101 representing the field's prime modulus
>   polynomial x^8+x^4+x^3+x^2+1.

which is all pretty much greek to me.

So my question is this: What is the easiest way to perform addition and multiplication in this kind of Galois field arithmetic? Assume both input numbers are 8 bits wide, and my output needs to be 8 bits wide also. Several implementations precalculate, or hardcode in two lookup tables to help with this, but I am not sure how those are calculated, or how I would use them in this situation. I would rather not take the 512 byte memory hit for the two tables, but it really depends on what the alternative is. I really just need help understanding how to do a single multiplication and addition operation in this circuit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In practice only one table is needed. That would be for the GP(256) multiply. Note that all arithmetic is carry-less, meaning that there is no carry-propagation.

Addition and subtraction without carry is equivalent  to an xor.

So in GF(256), `a + b` and `a - b` are both equivalent to `a xor b`.

GF(256) multiplication is also carry-less, and can be done using carry-less multiplication in a similar way with carry-less addition/subtraction. This can be done efficiently with hardware support via say [Intel's CLMUL instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLMUL_instruction_set).

However, the hard part, is reducing the modulo `100011101`. In normal integer division, you do it using a series of compare/subtract steps. In GF(256), you do it in a nearly identical manner using a series of compare/xor steps.

In fact, it's bad enough where it's still faster to just precompute all 256 x 256 multiplies and put them into a 65536-entry look-up table.

page 3 of the following pdf has a pretty good reference on GF256 arithmetic:

http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/CS222/eccnotes.pdf

Comment: Reducing addition to xor is great. a 65k lookup table is out of the question when I am working with <2k of ram. I can sacrifice time for memory when necessary, but I am still not clear on how a multiplication would work the long way.

Comment: It's actually very similar to the shift-add binary-multiplication algorithm. Except that you replace all the adds with xors.

Comment: When does the 100011101 come into play? Furthermore, why is that 9 bits when each byte is only 8?

Comment: It comes in when you do the modulus. The extra bit is implicit. (though it's been a while so I'm not sure how to explain it) I'll see if I can dig up my example code

Comment: I found my code that does the multiply-mod in GF(256). But it relies on the CLMUL instruction. I don't have time right now to expand on it, so I'll do it tomorrow. (unless someone gives a better answer by then)

Comment: looking at the zxing source: they use this formula for multiplication: int logSum = logTable[a] + logTable[b];
    return expTable[(logSum % size) + logSum / size];  Is that sufficient? It would require both tables, but that may be acceptable.

Comment: I've never seen that formula before - let alone know how it works. Are you sure that is for GF(256)? It seems like log-tables shouldn't work in modular field. (though I may be completely wrong)

Comment: Both 256 byte tables are precalculated through a process I don't understand. They are essentially inverses of each other. Source is http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/common/reedsolomon/GenericGF.java

Comment: I'll take a look at that link tomorrow after my final. As weak as my math is, this *is* a topic that fascinates me.

Comment: @Mysticial - 10010010 is not a valid poly for GF(256), it should be 9 bits, and the least significant bit needs to be 1. It's not an extra bit, the modulo operation divides some n bit result by the 9 bit polynomial, resulting in an 8 bit remainder, and that remainder is the modulus. For 100011101, all non-zero numbers are powers of 1x+0 == 2. Multiply can be done using product = exp[(log[a]+log[b])%255]. The %255 can be done with `if (sum >= 255) sum -= 255`.

Comment: @rcgldr That's most likely a typo on my part. But given that it's been so many years, I do not recall what I actually used.

Comment: @Mysticial - reducing modulo can be done using carryless multiplies using the "inverse" of the polynomial. Using P(x) to represent the polynomial, then using 64 bit carryless math, the modulo of A = A xor ( (A x (2^64 / P(x) ) x P(x) ) (along with some shifts), where (2^64 / P(x)) is a pre-computed constant.

Comment: @Mysticial - Here is a [lengthy example](https://github.com/01org/isa-l/blob/master/crc/crc16_t10dif_01.asm) (500+ lines) using xmm registers and pclmulqdq , and here is a [Intel pdf doc](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/fast-crc-computation-generic-polynomials-pclmulqdq-paper.pdf) . Look at the "Barret reduction part", where constants for (2^64 / P(x)) and P(x) are used along with shifts.

Answer (score 6):

(I'm following up on the pointer to zxing in the first answer, since I'm the author.)

The answer about addition is exactly right; that's why working in this field is convenient on a computer.

See http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/common/reedsolomon/GenericGF.java

Yes multiplication works, and is for GF256. a * b is really the same as exp(log(a) + log(b)). And because GF256 has only 256 elements, there are only 255 unique powers of "x", and same for log. So these are easy to put in a lookup table. The tables would "wrap around" at 256, so that is why you see the "% size". "/ size" is slightly harder to explain in a sentence -- it's because really 1-255 "wrap around", not 0-255. So it's not quite just a simple modulus that's needed.

The final piece perhaps is how you reduce modulo an irreducible polynomial. The irreducibly polynomial is x^8 plus some lower-power terms, right -- call it I(x) = x^8 + R(x). And the polynomial is congruent to 0 in the field, by definition; I(x) == 0. So x^8 == -R(x). And, conveniently, addition and subtraction are the same, so x^8 == -R(x) == R(x).

The only time we need to reduce higher-power polynomials is when constructing the exponents table. You just keep multiplying by x (which is a shift left) until it gets too big -- gets an x^8 term. But x^8 is the same as R(x). So you take out the x^8 and add in R(x). R(x) merely has powers up to x^7 so it's all in a byte still, all in GF(256). And you know how to add in this field.

Helps?

Comment: So if I read correctly, simply using bytes with wraparound and adding would not be adequate? Div and mod are rather expensive operations, so an addition only way would be best. I can implement byte addition that wraps 254->255->1->2 if necessary.

Comment: Ah the expert finally steps in... +1

Comment: I'm actually having issues getting a reference implementation of the circuit concept working, even using the zxing code for the GF addition and multiplication. Maybe I will post details to the zxing forum.

Comment: If you know that the field size is 256, then the `/` and `%` operations are really just `>>8` and `&0xFF`. I imagine you could optimize this a little more. But, in the QR code decoding process, the Reed-Solomon error correction process is a very small part. I would be surprised if this is your bottleneck at all.