# Galois field (GF) with R

Tags: r, galois-field

Is there any package for Galois fields (GF) in R? I would like to define the following matrix operations with GF.

- **1+1=0**
- 1+0=1
- 0+1=1
- 0+0=0

Obviously R doesn't understand the `1+1` without specifying it:

```
> k <- matrix(c(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1), ncol=10);k
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0     1
> p <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1), ncol=10);p
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    1    0     1
> c <- k+p;c
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    2    1    0    1    0     2
```

Comment: Is that the **only** GF you want to use? Or are you looking for advice on implementing an arbitrary field's operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about Galois fields, but from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440654/addition-and-multiplication-in-a-galois-field) it appears that addition and subtraction are equivalent to `xor`. It might be easier to just use this fact to do your computations.

```
as.integer(xor(k,p))
```

Or, if you want to get really fancy, you can overload the operator and define your own class:

```
`+.GF`<-function (x, y) as.integer((x | y) & !(x & y))
class(k)<-'GF'
class(p)<-'GF'
k+p
[1] 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just define a function yourself.  It looks like you're just doing boolean arithmetic.

```
myadd <- function(x, y){(x+y) %% 2}
```

Example

```
> a <- matrix(c(0,0,1,1),2,2)
> b <- matrix(c(0,1,0,1),2,2)
> a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1
> b
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    1    1
> myadd(a,b)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    0
```