# Escape characters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file

I am reading a file using fileread() which returns me the entire file. Now I need to read line by line and convert them into process the data. Can I know how I would be able to detect the newline character in Matlab? I tried '\n' and '\r\n' and it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And by the way, can someone tell how can I add math in my questions?

Comment: You might want to look at the [zxing implementation for GF math](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/common/reedsolomon/GenericGF.java) as a reference. (Found via related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/8440654)

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: Thanks Jonas !I generally use Python or MATLAB for any mathematical calculations. I have found a way to do though it may not be completely efficient! I'll soon answer the question myself. Thanks

Comment: Gfconv in MATLAB is a very efficient function for multiplication! (Check gfdeconv()for polynomial division

Comment: I would look for the file exchange for solution that might already do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For special acharacters either use the [char](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) function with the character code (http://www.asciitable.com/) or sprintf (my preferred way for better readability.
For example you are looking for sprintf('\n') or sprintf('\r\n')

char(13) is carriage return \r
char(10) is new line \n

Comment: That works fine with sprintf() or fprintf(). But when I use fscanf() i am not able to retrieve the escape character. 

I need to do this
    s =fileread('some_file.txt')
    if s(i) == '\n'
Do something
elseif s(i) == '\0'
Do something else

Comment: if s(i) == sprintf('n') is maybe what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file line by line (see [fgetl](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html)):

```
fid = fopen ( 'file', 'r' );
% Check that it opened okay
if fid ~= -1
  while ( true )
    line = fgetl ( fid );
    % Check for end of file
    if line == -1; break; end
    %Do stuff with line;
  end
  fclose ( fid );
end
```

Comment: how can i recognise the '\t' and '\0'. Please help