# What are the matlab equivalent for '\n' '\t' and other escape characters?

Tags: matlab, file, escaping

I am reading a file using fileread() which returns me the entire file. Now I need to read line by line and convert them into process the data. Can I know how I would be able to detect the newline character in Matlab? I tried '\n' and '\r\n' and it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible to put this question as bounty? I need the answer urgently?

Comment: You can just compare with the ASCII codes directly, such as `10` or `13`

Answer (score 0):

I already replied here (please avoid posting the question twice)[Escape characters in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633542/escape-characters-in-matlab/43177697#43177697)

For special acharacters either use the char function with the character code (http://www.asciitable.com/) or sprintf (my preferred way for better readability. For example you are looking for sprintf('\n') or sprintf('\r\n')

char(13) is carriage return \r char(10) is new line \n